# What allows ovaries to fuse to form a multiple fruit?

Tags: botany, fruit, flowers

If these ovaries are from different flowers but from a single inflorescence, what makes it possible for these ovaries to fuse or produce a single mass? Furthermore, what exactly is the process of forming a multiple fruit?